# Camera through HDMI?

Tags: camera, pi-2, hdmi, display

The display I have connected to my Raspberry Pi has a built-in camera on the top. Can I access this through my raspberry pi as I might a USB webcam?

I'm currently running ubuntu mate on the pi in question, but I have a raspbian SD too.

The monitor in question:
[image: monitor]

The monitor is a [Lenovo L215p 21.5-inch Wide Flat Panel LCD Monitor](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/migr-73082)

Comment: Via the desktop or a program that fills the entire screen?

Comment: Via the desktop, but also via the command line. I'd like to access it in all the ways I could use a raspberry pi camera module.

Comment: What display are you using?

Comment: Hold on, I'll look.

Comment: I've edited my post to include a picture, I'm looking up the model

Comment: The monitor is this one https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/migr-73082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot access it via HDMI, as the camera in your monitor is a USB webcam and has nothing to do with the HDMI system of the monitor.

You can only access it via your USB host interface, or via something hosting it as a USB peripheral and forwarding the data to your pi (for example, you could plug it into a another pi and have that send you the data over a network).

Comment: I believe I had the webcam working through HDMI on a Mac Mini, without connecting it with USB

Comment: That seems highly unlikely, both based on how these are made and on the lack of any mention of such capability in the manual: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/docs/UM013235   You should probably repeat the alleged test.

Comment: I used this monitor for years with a 2010 Mac mini. After buying a new monitor for that, I moved it to a raspberry pi. I'm positive the monitor could pass camera data through the HDMI port. If the raspberry pi does not support this capability, that's fine, but the monitor does. It's possible the monitor I linked to is not the same, but they seem to be visually identical, and made in the same year.

Comment: You are mistaken in your recollection.

Comment: I may be mistaken. On second thought, I did have this monitor connected through USB. I had assumed this was only for the built-in USB hub, but maybe it passed camera data as well. Thanks for your help.